# Match the corresponding equation to the RC circuit

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, resistors, homework

By trial and error, I have found that the equation for circuit 1 is the second equation listed.

Can someone please take the time to explain this to me.

I have been working to "combine" the circuit elements, (RC in parallel with RC), but then I realised that this may not help to find v out.

By doing KVL, I still could not understand how the equation for v out came to the the second equation listed.

Thank you very much for your time.

[image: Image of questions]

Comment: The shunt components across the voltage source not in series with output have no effect and may be deleted

Comment: I just want to emphasize what @Tony wrote. The question isn't asking you about the load seen by the input source. The input source will drive the first R+C but that has nothing to do with the output. It's just another load to the input source and doesn't affect the output. So mentally delete them. You are left with just a very simple C/(R+C) voltage divider: $$\frac{\frac{1}{j\:\omega\:C}}{R+\frac{1}{j\:\omega\:C}}\cdot\frac{j\:\omega\:C}{j\:\omega\:C}=\frac{1}{1+j\:\omega\:R\:C}$$

Comment: Discounting anything attached at the output of circuit 1 (which isn't shown), the load on the input source will be \$\frac{1}{2}\left(R+\frac{1}{j\:\omega\:C}\right)\$. You should be able to see why, too. Also, I think this question isn't so good as equation 2 and 3 are identical.

Comment: Fix your picture. It's unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

The output Vc(f) = Ic(f)*Zc(f) Ohm’s Law

Thus\$ Vc = \dfrac{Vin}{Zc+R}*Zc, ~~ Zc=1/\omega C\$

The confusion may come from Vin is shown as Vin(t) but expects answer for Vin(f)